# Radlibrary not returning all ads from Meta/Facebook Ad Library

Tags: r, facebook

I am trying to get all ads from different political pages on Facebook using the `Radlibrary` package in R -- which I have done a hundred times before with no problem at all. Now I experience that some ads are not returned -- there`s no system in which ads are not returned: for one party it is just a few ads in april 2022, for another it's all ads after 1/1/2021 -- but the thing in common is that I get **some of the ads**.

The problem is similar to the one described here: https://github.com/facebookresearch/Radlibrary/issues/103

Also, I know the ads are available since they are 1) displayed both in the browser version of the Ad Library but also if I download them as a .csv file from facebook.com/ads/library and 2) I have managed to get the ads that now are missing in a previous pull a couple of months ago

My code is (which only returns 117 out of 210 ads):

```
library("Radlibrary")

query_ad <- adlib_build_query(ad_reached_countries = 'DK',
                              ad_active_status = 'ALL',
                              search_terms = "NULL",
                              search_page_ids = "223040066022",
                              fields = c(
                                "id",
                                "ad_creation_time",
                                "ad_creative_bodies",
                                "ad_delivery_start_time",
                                "ad_delivery_stop_time",
                                "ad_snapshot_url",
                                "currency",
                                "page_id",
                                "page_name",
                                "publisher_platforms",
                                "impressions",
                                "spend"
                              ))

response_ad <- adlib_get_paginated(query_ad, max_gets = 10, token = token)

results_tibble_ad <- as_tibble(response_ad, type = "ad",
                               censor_access_token = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved [in the newest release](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Radlibrary/blob/main/NEWS.md#radlibrary-042).